# Such a crappy riddle

Tags: riddle

I'm on patrol
I'm on a roll!
I want to clean
Could you please lean?

What could I be?

---

Your answer should be one or two words, depending on how you spell this well-used phrase. Make sure you provide an explanation.

> Bonus Question (And a hint): How many should you take? (Answer is in the riddle as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion (somewhat too straightforward)

> bathroom tissue (or toilet paper, etc.)

Because

> It's usually on a roll and used for cleaning. Also, the title hints :)

Comment: I wonder if the bonus is rot13(Pbhyq vg or sbhe furrgf fvapr rnpu yvar vf sbhe flyynoyrf)?

Comment: Precisely :) Some even prefer HALF that, but they are crazy.